# Django Admin: Heading below Entries?

Tags: css, django-admin, bootstrap-5

If I add Bootstrap5 CSS, then the heading of the entries is suddenly at the bottom:

[image: heading-below-entries]

If I uncomment this, it is back to normal:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Is there a way to get both: normal heading and BS5?

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution: [caption-side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caption-side)

```
caption {
    caption-side: top;
}
```

Now the blue heading is on top again.